# Grammatical function of "allow me to say" in "I know you despise me; allow me to say, it is because you don't understand me.”

Tags: sentence-construction

> “I know you despise me; **allow me to say**, it is because you don't understand me.” ― Elizabeth Gaskell, *North and South*

How may I grammatically discern *allow me to say*?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "grammatically discern", but it might help you to classify ***allow me to say*** there as a [discourse marker](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv316.shtml).

Comment: I'm also unsure what "grammatically discern" means. However, in your sentence, "allow" is an imperative. (Not that I disagree with FumbleFingers's comment.)

Comment: So this seems like a discourse marker. Yes. I think that seemed information I aimed to get. I guess I got trouble discerning if it seemed like a phrase. So I guess it seems a discourse marker like *And indeed*,. I thank you, FumbleFingers.

Comment: Many questioners use "discern". A more linguistically acceptable way to ask is "what function does [x] serve in this sentence?" Or, traditionally, "How do I parse [x]?".

Answer (score 1):

As FumbleFingers pointed out, in this sentence "allow me to say" is being used as a discourse marker ([BBC](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv316.shtml), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discourse_marker)).

The Wikipedia article splits discourse markers into categories:

> Those functions can be classified into three broad groups: (a) relationships among (parts of) utterances; (b) relationships between the speaker and the message, and (c) relationships between speaker and hearer.

This marker would be in group (c). As the speaker has just mentioned, the listener despises her. You might not expect someone that despises you to let you speak or listen to what you have to say. Here, the speaker is saying to let them speak despite this attitude.

Its function is similar to 'however', in that an additional thought is coming and it signals a contradiction, but the contradiction is more with the relationship between the speaker and the listener than with the previous thought (although in this case the previous thought was a statement of that relationship).